# Convert numbers to arrays

Tags: arrays

Question for javascript, why do we need to convert numbers to string then only it can be converted to arrays?

```js
const numbers =12345;
const stringNumbers = numbers.toString();
const array =[];

for(let i = 0 ; i < stringNumbers.length; i++){
    array.push(stringNumbers[i]);
}

["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current approach, you are simply iterating over the characters of the number string, and inserting them into the array one by one.  Well, that of course necessitates that the number first be converted into a string.  Here is an approach which avoids the string conversion entirely:

```js
var numbers = 12345;
var array = [];

while (numbers > 0) {
    array.push(numbers % 10);
    numbers = Math.floor(numbers / 10);
}
array = array.reverse();

console.log(array);
```